# Sex of fern gametophytes

Tags: botany

The following image is from Campbell Biology, 12th edition
[image: fern life cycle]

It says, "Each gametophyte develops sperm-producing organs called antheridia and egg-producing organs called archegonia". This seems to suggest gametophytes are either *always* hermaphrodites or *most of the times* hermaphrodites.

I have done a little bit of searching and now am convinced that they are not *always* hermaphrodites.

> "Most ferns, on the other hand, are homosporous; they produce a single
> type of spore. After germination, each fern spore has the potential to
> develop into a male, female, or hermaphrodite gametophyte."

[https://science.sciencemag.org/content/346/6208/423.summary#:~:text=Most%20ferns%2C%20on%20the%20other,%2C%20female%2C%20or%20hermaphrodite%20gametophyte](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/346/6208/423.summary#:%7E:text=Most%20ferns%2C%20on%20the%20other,%2C%20female%2C%20or%20hermaphrodite%20gametophyte).

Are they most of the time hermaphrodites? How common are unisexual gametophytes?

Comment: Your image has text (top) that reads "**most** fern species produce a single type of spore that develops into a bisexual photosynthetic gametophyte." So right in that source, you know already that no one is claiming that they are **always** bisexual (by which they seem to mean hermaphrodites), and a statement that they are both hermaphrodites. I do not see any conflict between the textbook and the quote, and the textbook at least seems to think that they are mostly hermaphrodites. Generally, making  statements with the word "always" is a bad idea in biology.

Comment: @MaximilianPress There is a contradiction. 
a) Most fern species are hermaphrodite
b) Most fern species have the potential to become  a male, female or a hermaphrodite.   
a) and b) are potentially contradictory. 

My question was about the ratio. what is Male:Female:Hermaphrodite gametophytes? The answer will depend of the species ofcourse. So can be a complicated. But It can be easy too, for example Overwhelming majorities of gametophytes may be hermaphrodite

Comment: I do not see that your statements (a) and (b) are contradictory. Obviously the implication is that unisexual gametophytes are relatively rare, as you suggest. I am not a fern biologist so I don't know about relative proportions, but measurements of these proportions have been done in at least some species, e.g. https://www.jstor.org/stable/23728097?seq=1, which do show slight majorities of bisexual gametophytes in the lab and in the field.